# Allow anyone to upload to my GDRIVE using google api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a php file upload form, which allows users to store uploaded images to their gdrive.

But i want to change that as who ever upload a image using that form, will be stored in a one gdrive. and i want users to allow upload without login to their google account.

ex: 100 users can upload files to "MY Grive" without login to google accounts.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).

> For these types of server-to-server interactions you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end-user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required. (In non-service-account scenarios, your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.)

You may also want to see [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).

> 1. Open the Service accounts section of the Developers Console's Permissions page.
> 2. Click Create service account.
> 3. In the Create service account window, type a name for the service account and select Furnish a new private key. If you want to grant Google Apps domain-wide authority to the service account, also select Enable Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation. Then, click Create.